# Necessary fingerprint length etc. when Alice wants to send multiple pseudonymous messages in public to Bob and keep option of proving authorship later

Tags: rsa, key

Alice wants to send Bob messages. She has the following requirements.

1. She plans to send him messages that are sequentially numbered, pseudonymous, and sent to him publicly over a period of time.
2. Each message will take the form of a single text file.
3. She wants Bob (and indeed anyone else who is interested) to be able to verify soon after he receives each message that it is from the same sender as all previous messages, but right now she does not want him know that she is that person.
4. She wants to be able to prove at a later date, if she feels like it, that she is that person.
5. She does not trust online key servers.
6. She does not trust sites such as 4chan.
7. She wants to start by publishing a PGP RSA-1 fingerprint publicly, e.g. perhaps she will get it into a photograph in a large-circulation hardcopy newspaper and then make it "common knowledge" that that edition contained the right fingerprint.
8. She wants that fingerprint to be as short as possible but long enough not to be hackable, meaning that nobody else can feasibly make a key pair in which the public key has the same fingerprint.
9. She does not want to be defeated by Chuck. Chuck is a bad guy who will certainly read the genuine messages and who is capable of sending fake messages to Bob. For example Chuck may try to swamp Alice's messages by sending Bob fake messages (perhaps a large number of them)
   a) through the same public channel as genuine messages,
   b) that purport to be in the sequence,
   c) that are divided into three parts just like genuine messages,
   d) that have a content quite close to the "kind of thing" that Alice would write, but have subtle differences that serve Chuck's wicked purposes,
   e) that use a public key with a fingerprint that is as close to Alice's fingerprint as Chuck can get, and
   f) that verify as legitimate using a public key (included in his messages) that has that fingerprint.

**How should Alice proceed?**

In particular, what length of public key and password will be sufficient? Am I right that the answers are "4096 bits" and "40 characters"? And will the following advice included in each genuine message be sufficient?

> TO BOB FROM ALICE: VERIFICATION INSTRUCTIONS:
>
> This document is in three parts: P (main text), Q (public key), and R (signature).
> To verify its authenticity, take the following steps.
>
> - A. Retrieve the 40-character fingerprint X from [presumed unfakeable place, e.g. a certain issue of a printed newspaper]
> - B. Create a text file, copy Q into it as its entire content, and save it as "Q.asc".
> - C. Use a PGP program to find the fingerprint Y of Q.
> - D. Verify that X = Y. **If it does not, this message is fake**. If and only if it does, take the next three steps.
> - E. Create a second text file, copy P into it as its entire content, and save it as "P.txt" in the same folder as "Q.asc".
> - F. Create a third text file, copy R into it as its entire content, and save it as "R.asc" in the same folder as "P.txt" and "Q.asc".
> - G. Use a PGP program to verify that R is the authentic signature of P using the public key Q.
>   **If it is, and if you are sure that X=Y, then this document is authentic. Otherwise, it is fake**.

These verification instructions would be included in the "main text" of each message, i.e. part P.

Maybe there's a less complicated way she can do this?

Comment: This really looks like a homework question. Is it? If not, can you explain the purpose for a brand new implementation and the ultimate goal?

Comment: You have a lot of weird and unnecessary requirements without explanation: "She does not trust sites such as 4chan." -- what's the relevance? "She wants that fingerprint to be as short as possible" -- why? And your whole threat model for "Chuck" makes a ton of assumptions that defeat anything you've come up as a mitigation, else you have not explained the relevant details about the threat Chuck poses. "divided into three parts" -- that's a new detail without antecedent. "close fingerprints" -- what does that even mean and how is it relevant?

Comment: "what length of public key and password will be sufficient?" - nothing you've described so far will help answer that. So we can't comment on whether you are correct in your assumptions.

Comment: No, it's not a homework question. The purpose is personal enlightenment. The relevance of not trusting 4chan is that unless I am mistaken it's possible to post messages there which carry a unique authorial ID. I read that somewhere. If it's not so, I'll remove that bit.

Comment: You don't trust cryptographic key servers, but you trust a newspaper? Can you explain the disparity in trust?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "anything you've come up as a mitigation". "Divided into three parts" means text, key, and fingerprint. I would have thought some of the experts on this site would be able to answer the key length part of this question right away without needing more "details". Let's see.

Comment: You asked about "sufficiency" but have not described what it needs to be sufficient ***for***.

Comment: @schroeder - Why do you ask me to explain a disparity in trust? I am asking a hypothetical question. I am not planning to send any pseudonymous messages to anyone. A printed newspaper is printed in a large number of copies, and perhaps hundreds or thousands of each issue are archived in public libraries. A webserver has a single on-off switch. Just assume Alice can make the fingerprint reliably publicly available. It doesn't matter how or why, or why she prefers say Le Monde to 4chan.

Comment: Why are you trying to provide a pseudo-code process *in each communication* to explain  what could be provided as a simple command that includes verification? I'm really not sure what you are trying to ask here, and your goal in all this. It's a bit of a tangled mess.

Comment: The disparity in trust helps to define the goals and the threat model that is being considered. This whole thing, as I stated, has a whole bunch of weird requirements and details without any provided relevance. We don't know what's important, what's required, and what's an imagined implementation detail. You're asking if all this "is enough", but we, and you, need to be very clear about what it needs to be good enough ***for***.

Comment: "Is 40 char long enough?" Dunno. What's Chuck's capacity to crack keys? A 2 char fingerprint could be enough. Or a 100 char fingerprint could not be enough.

Comment: "Is there a less complicated way to do this?" Sure. Alice does what everyone else does: get Bob and her to use PGP in email and pass her key to Bob. How does *anything* in your post provide anything better than that?

Comment: What is the problem, @schroeder? You've posted 9 comments! Perhaps Alice is in love with Bob. I have no idea. She's imaginary. Regarding sufficiency, see pts 3,4,9. No comments here from me after this one now. I don't care what a fictitious person's "ultimate goal" might be, or why she doesn't trust a website where people are said to be able to achieve such-and-such. I simply wanted to exclude "Try posting somewhere like 4chan" as an answer. If you can expand on "simple command that includes verification" in a way that I can understand, please do so in an answer.

Comment: I'm not asking about Alice's goal. This is ***your question and your process***. I'm asking you, not her.

Comment: My problem is that this entire thing is unanswerable and I'm trying to help you create something answerable. You're refusing to provide clarity or engage in the process. So, this gets closed. Have a good day.

Comment: Please don't be sarcastic. There must be a limit to what length of key is generally thought to be secure right now. Assume Chuck might be the NSA but he isn't Superman. As for your "send him an email" comment, I specified in the header and also in point 1 that she wants to send the messages in public. I don't care why. I'm not writing a story here. Please remove some of your comments. If you have some points to make, organise them into an answer please. I am happy to edit to improve the question if required.

Comment: Don't have a tantrum.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. I'm highlighting the problem. The only relevant detail for whether the length is sufficient is Chuck's capacity. If Chuck is the NSA, then that is *absolutely* a relevant detail here and no, 40 chars are not enough. Do you understand now?  Your question, without all the weird details, is actually quite simple: how does one sign a public communication and maintain the integrity of the signing process and identity integrity, while maintaining anonymity? If the weird details are important to you, then we need to know why.

Comment: One more personal attack via a petty vandalisation of this post will get your account suspended.